# Keep every data entry per ID given one condition

Tags: sql

the following data is given:

```
ID   CODE
1    A
1    B
1    C
1    D
2    A
2    B  
2    C
3    C
3    D
```

I need to keep the IDs and every CODE documented, GIVEN that code A is documented.
Further, is it possible to count how many DISTINCT IDs are excluded due to this circumstance?

Want:

```
ID   Code
1    A
1    B
1    C
1    D
2    A
2    B  
2    C
```

Thank you

PP

Comment: Why should ID 3 be excluded from the result.

Comment: Because ID 3 has no entry of 'A' in the column CODE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In combnation with EXISITS, you get a fast possility to chekc if code A is present for any id

```
SELECT ID, CODE
FROM tab t1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tab WHERE ID = t1.ID AND CODe = 'A')
```

| ID | CODE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 1 | D |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | C |

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT ID) FROM tab t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tab WHERE ID = t1.ID AND CODe = 'A')
```

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/j9Z-GzY-)

Comment: Thank you. Works fine! What if my table was generated by joining two tables? Same solution or different?

Comment: yes you can make a CTE and use it as you would in my example. If you have problems post a new question with a simplified join as fiddle and someone like me can take a look